# Cannot get value from calling constant function with web3js and Metamask

Tags: web3js, dapps, metamask, javascript

I have an extremely basic contract deployed on Ropsten:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract hypergrowth {
  uint256 public someNumber = 5;

  function hypergrowth() public {}

  function changeNumber(uint256 number) public {
    someNumber = number;
  }

  function getNumber() public constant returns (uint256 someNumber) {
    return someNumber;
  }
}
```

I use web3js and Metamask to interact with the deployed contract.

I can initialize web3. I can get the primary account from Metamask. But I always get 0 when I call getNumber(). Here are the functions that I use with web3:

```js
function getNumberFromContract(contract) {
  contract.getNumber( (err, res) => {
    console.log(res.toNumber());
  });
}

function setNumberFromContract(contract) {
  contract.changeNumber(10, function(err,res){
    console.log("done");
  });
}
```

I don't get why I receive 0...I can't even see if setNumber() works.

What do I do wrong?

UPDATE:

I use this code to wait for the getNumber function to execute:

```js
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function () {
    deferred.resolve(getNumberFromContract(hyperContract));
  }, 5000);
```

And still get 0.

UPDATE 2:

This is how I get the contract:

```js
var address = '0xbabd1c95906d4ebec8977a7d0f32410ecba1103f';
var abi = [
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getNumber",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "number",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "changeNumber",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "constructor"
  }
];
var hyperContract = getContract(abi, web3.eth.accounts[0], web3);
```

The `getContract` function is this:

```js
function getContract(ABI, address, web3) {
  return web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(address);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you invoke your function "getContract" with an EOA address and not the contract address !

change :

```js
var hyperContract = getContract(abi, web3.eth.accounts[0], web3);
```

by :

```js
var hyperContract = getContract(abi, address, web3); // (As address var is defined above)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the transaction to be mined.

This line:

`console.log("done");`

should more accurately read:

`console.log("sent");`

You could output the transaction receipt for giggles (`res`). The next step is check periodically to see if the transaction is mined. Once it's mined/confirmed, you can go ahead with your getter and based on just eyeballing the code, it looks like it will work.

Here's a gist that shows a way to wait for confirmation before proceeding with the next step.

https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried with a deffered object and wait 5 seconds. Still doesn't work. I updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with your function is the return variable `someNumber` is shadowing the global variable with the same name `someNumber`.

```
uint256 public someNumber = 5;

// ..

function getNumber() public constant returns (uint256 someNumber) {
    return someNumber;    //   <---  Here someNumber is 0
}
```